# Git mysteriously deleting all files upon commit

Tags: git

I'm pretty new to Git (and version control in general) and am ashamed to say that this problem has been going on for a while now. Occasionally, after adding changes, git will delete everything from my repository upon the following commit.

Afterward I add and commit again, and it creates everything it just deleted.

It hasn't caused any issues, but I can't imagine this is a good thing, and I'm beginning to get more and more freaked out by it.

Oops. I'm just using the commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m "blah blah"
```

Comment: Along with the commands, it'd be cool if you could recreate this with a simple test repo... it sounds like you have a really cool problem! (or you're just doing something silly; we've all been there)

Comment: I think you forgot the traditional rain dance needed to appease Linus.

Comment: i thought i had notifications turned on-- i didn't. thanks for the replies. i'll try to recreate the issue, though the inconsistency with which the error shows up makes me think it'd take a while to show up... i half-suspect that it has something to do with the bloatedness of my repository.